# Appending text to the body background image with fadeToggle() effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

It is an important project for me and I have been trying to find a way how to prevent a text from being appended to the `body` over and over again. I have different slides which appear everytime when you hit the *right arrow* or *up arrow keys*. When you hit ***'p'*** you *pause* slides and you will see a *body background image*. Using `append()` function I am adding a text to the image. Unfortunately, the text keeps being appended when you *pause* or *play*. So far I tried to use `hide()`, `fadeOut()`, `one()` even `dequeue()` to stop it but no success. How can I have the text to be appended to the body once ? `fadeToggle()` function works fine showing and hiding body background image only the text is causing an issue

```
  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        var text = $("<p.text>PRESS 'P' TO GO BACK</p.text>");
        if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40 ||   event.keyCode == 32) {
        next(); // right arrow and bottom arrow keys
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38){
        back(); // left arrow and up arrow keys
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 80){  // 'p' key to pause and play 
            $('.slides').fadeToggle();
            $('body').append(text).hide();
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
   body {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    background: url("bodyBack.png");
}
```

It is not a complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .. and let me know Is that what you need or not

```
var notappend = true;
     $(document).keyup(function(event) {
            var text = $("<p.text>PRESS 'P' TO GO BACK</p.text>");
            if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40 ||   event.keyCode == 32) {
            next(); // right arrow and bottom arrow keys
            }
            else if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38){
            back(); // left arrow and up arrow keys
            }
            else if(event.keyCode == 80){  // 'p' key to pause and play
                $('.slides').fadeToggle(); 
                if(notappend == true){
                    $('body').append(text);
                    notappend = false;
                }else{
                    //notappend == true;
                }

            }
        });
```

try to work around  notappend == true; and notappend == false; to get what you want

Comment: @alpha please check my answer again .. I'm not doing anything in your code .. I just but append inside if statement .. and please always check your console

Comment: after hitting 'p' again I don't see slides back appeared ... It is just completely white background even body image disappeared

Comment: hide() functions completely hides body background image

Comment: I found the answer I removed .hide() and now it works

Comment: Can you please remove hide() from your code after .append(text) so I can accept your answer ?

Comment: @alpha please before you accept my answer check well  is your code works fine or not

Comment: It is functioning fine. Thanks for your help with a boolean value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78051/discussion-between-alpha-and-mohamed-yousef).